# Host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1130

This should be dead simple, but I *cannot* get it to work for the life of me.
I'm just trying to connect remotely to my MySQL server.

- Connecting as:

  ```bash
  mysql -u root -h localhost -p
  ```
- works fine, but trying:

  ```bash
  mysql -u root -h 'any ip address here' -p
  ```
- fails with the error:

  > ERROR 1130 (00000): Host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

In the `mysql.user` table, there is exactly the same entry for user 'root' with host 'localhost' as another with host '%'.

I'm at my wits' end and have no idea how to proceed.
Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Can't login as root in most circumstances due to security precaution..

Answer (score 1078, accepted):

Possibly a security precaution. You could try adding a new administrator account:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Although as Pascal and others have noted it's not a great idea to have a user with this kind of access open to any IP. If you need an administrative user, use root, and leave it on localhost. For any other action specify exactly the privileges you need and limit the accessibility of the user as Pascal has suggest below.

Edit:

From the MySQL FAQ:

> If you cannot figure out why you get
>   Access denied, remove from the user 
>   table all entries that have Host
>   values containing wildcards (entries
>   that contain '%' or '_' characters). A
>   very common error is to insert a new
>   entry with Host='%' and
>   User='some_user', thinking that this
>   allows you to specify localhost to
>   connect from the same machine. The
>   reason that this does not work is that
>   the default privileges include an
>   entry with Host='localhost' and
>   User=''. Because that entry has a Host
>   value 'localhost' that is more
>   specific than '%', it is used in
>   preference to the new entry when
>   connecting from localhost! The correct
>   procedure is to insert a second entry
>   with Host='localhost' and
>   User='some_user', or to delete the
>   entry with Host='localhost' and
>   User=''. After deleting the entry,
>   remember to issue a FLUSH PRIVILEGES
>   statement to reload the grant tables.
>   See also Section 5.4.4, “Access
>   Control, Stage 1: Connection
>   Verification”.

Comment: Good catch Yannick, however I would not recommend him granting all privileges to a non-root user. Perhaps a reduced set?

Comment: Well, this indeed wouldn't be a good idea, but allowing 'root' to connect from all hosts is exactly the same, since it is at the same privilege level.

Comment: I think you miss my point Pascal. The point is that the 'root' user has those rights already, and he wants to let any ip authenticate as that user. So if this is really what he wants, the default example of creating a new administrator user (which has exactly the same rights) is an alternative to what he's trying.

Comment: That's right Yannick, I read to fast and will remove my comment. However, AFAIK, permissions are working fine in MySQL so: 1. maybe the OP modified the grant tables manually and then need to flush privileges. 2. maybe he didn't use the proper grant syntax for root. Adding another administrative user might be a workaround but it won't solve the real issue IMHO.

Comment: I felt that providing access from all hosts to root was not a proper solution. Instead I created a new user and granted a reduced set of privileges, the set I used is described as 'DBManager' on MySQL Workbench. I also only allowed access from a certain group of hosts in my local network, particularly 192.168.0.%

Comment: Thanks. 
Using GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'  
helped me resolve the error

Comment: This is a correct answer for root, which always has a localhost entry. However, if you are creating a brand new, non-root user, you do not need to add a localhost entry. Just issue *one* command creating the user with % as the hostname.

Comment: Don't forget ```FLUSH PRIVILEGES;``` to apply changes

Comment: You are my hero for the day!! Thanks a lot. I was trying to connect from a docker container to a localhost mysql and this is the only change that worked

Comment: How would you remove access? For example, yesterday my IP from home was one value but I had to restart my modem and now I have a new IP. I'd like to remove the old IP and add the new one.

Answer (score 380):

One has to create a `new MySQL User` and assign privileges as below in `Query prompt` via phpMyAdmin or command prompt:

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Once done with all four queries, it should connect with `username / password`

Comment: Had to restart mysql after completing the above steps for this to work for me.

Comment: Do you have to create username@localhost? Is it not enough if you just create username@% ?  I mean, if you just create username@%, will you not be able to connect with that user from localhost?

Comment: yeah creating a `@localhost` would make sense if the privileges were different somehow but here they're the same and it's probably going to be more confusing than anything (such as changing passwords on one not realizing the other exists and that your login might be hitting that one).

Comment: as a beginner it really helped me

Comment: thank it solves my "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host 'DESKTOP-xxx.xx' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server" in containerized  laravel application in windows

Comment: What can I do if I cannot even get into mysql with the command mysql -u root -p? or even phpmyadmin (using xampp)

Comment: not working in my case. see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62097919/how-to-properly-connect-mysql-database-with-c-sharp-application

Comment: i tried this but after doing that i get this error when i test the connection:

2059 - Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(../Frameworks/caching_sha2_password.so, 2): image not found

Comment: thanks. configuring remote access to your database is required.

Answer (score 139):

My error message was similar and said '*Host XXX is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server*' even though I was using root.  Here's how to make sure that root has the correct permissions.

**My setup**:

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- MySQL v5.5.37

**Solution**

1. Open up the file under `etc/mysql/my.cnf`
2. Check for:

   - **port** (by default this is `port = 3306`)
   - **bind-address** (by default this is `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`; if you want to open to all then just comment out this line.  For my example, I'll say the actual server is on 10.1.1.7)
3. Now access the MySQL Database on your actual server (say your remote address is 123.123.123.123 at port 3306 as user `root` and I want to change permissions on database 'dataentry'.  Remember to change the IP Address, Port, and database name to your settings)

   ```
   mysql -u root -p
   Enter password: <enter password>
   mysql>GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'123.123.123.123' IDENTIFIED BY 'put-your-password';
   mysql>FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   mysql>exit
   ```
4. sudo service mysqld restart
5. You should now be able to remote connect to your database.  For example, I'm using MySQL Workbench and putting in 'Hostname:10.1.1.7', 'Port:3306', 'Username:root'

Comment: You can skip the `use dataentry` line (since most people won't have that database created).

Comment: i was able to do this without restarting the `mysql` service at the end

Comment: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` should allow you to not need to restart.

Comment: This worked for me for MySQL 5.5 on Windows 10 with FLUSH PRIVILEGES, without restarting the service . On Windows, the service's properties should identify the my.ini file used for configuration (Properties | General | Path to executable)

Comment: I assumed that by specifying bind-address="0.0.0.0" it would listen on all interfaces and remote connections would work but I was wrong. Yes, netstat showed that mysql was listening on 0.0.0.0 (all interfaces) but I was getting the error in the question title. Once I removed the bind-address line completely, it started working. Weird.

Comment: i dont know why every time i run grant all its refer to create a user , instead of that i just update user column host "localhost" to "%" or specify my ip address then flush privilege and restart mysql its work .

Answer (score 99):

Just perform the following steps:

1. Connect to MySQL (via localhost)

   ```bash
   mysql -uroot -p
   ```

   - If the MySQL server is running in Kubernetes (K8s) and being accessed via a NodePort

     ```bash
     kubectl exec -it [pod-name] -- /bin/bash
     mysql -uroot -p
     ```

2. Create user

   ```sql
   CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
   ```
3. Grant permissions

   ```sql
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
   ```
4. Flush privileges

   ```sql
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```

Comment: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using passwoYES)Y

Comment: Should \\*.\\* be \*.\* ?

Comment: would this also work for similar problems with docker?  https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/12449/23443

Comment: How to do with mysql docker container?

Comment: `CREATE USER 'sammy'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` is different from `CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` the `%` its make it work like a charm.

Comment: I just want to clarify @YogiArifWidodo 's comment: the `%` makes it "work like a charm", because the percentage tells mysql to allow any host to connect. It's how you wildcard a host in mysql, as per the docs.

Answer (score 84):

You need to grant access to the user from any hostname.

This is how you add new privilege from phpmyadmin

Goto Privileges > Add a new User

[image]

Select **Any Host** for the desired username

[image]

Comment: This needs to be added to the MAMP for Mac help file I think. Still works in 2021

Answer (score 33):

Simple way:

```
Grant All Privileges ON *.* to 'USER_NAME'@'%' Identified By 'YOUR_PASSWORD';
```

then

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

done!

Comment: what does the % signify?

Comment: it's like everything. You can thing like example: `WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a%'` - Finds any values that start with "a"

Comment: gives SQL syntax error

Comment: @Sushil please write details

Answer (score 30):

The message `*Host ''xxx.xx.xxx.xxx'' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server` is a reply from the MySQL server to the MySQL client. Notice how its returning the IP address and not the hostname.

If you're trying to connect with `mysql -h<hostname> -u<somebody> -p` and it returns this message with the IP address, then the MySQL server isn't able to do a reverse lookup on the client. This is critical because thats how it maps the MySQL client to the grants.

Make sure you can do an `nslookup <mysqlclient>` FROM the MySQL server. If that doesn't work, then there's no entry in the DNS server. Alternatively, you can put an entry in the MySQL server's HOSTS file (`<ipaddress>  <fullyqualifiedhostname>   <hostname>` <- The order here might matter).

An entry in my server's host file allowing a reverse lookup of the MySQL client solved this very problem.

Comment: "is a reply from the MySQL server to the MySQL client." 

Thank you, I was wondering where the error was coming from, my machine or the server.  

I have error "ERROR 1130 (HY000):" etc.

Answer (score 27):

This working for any future remote mysql connection !

```
    sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

Navigate to the line that begins with the bind-address directive. It should look like this:

```
    bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

Login to your mysql as root terminal

```
    mysql -u root -p
    -- root password

    CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

    CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

    EXIT;
```

finally Grant that machine exclusive permission to connect to the database remotely with the following command.

```
    sudo ufw allow from remote_IP_address to any port 3306
```

Comment: Adding `'username'@'%'` fixed my issue as `'username'@'localhost'` is not enough, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 18):

If you modify the grant tables manually (using INSERT, UPDATE, etc.), you should execute 
a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` statement to tell the server to reload the grant tables.

PS: I wouldn't recommend to allow **any** host to connect for **any** user (especially not the `root` use). If you are using mysql for a client/server application, prefer a subnet address. If you are using mysql with a web server or application server, use specific IPs.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using MySQL WorkBench, you can achieve this easily:

1. From the menu, select Server -> Users And Privileges
   [image]
2. On the lower left, click on "Add account"
   [image]
3. Fill the form with username, host matching (% means every host) and the password
   [image]
4. Click on "Apply" on the lower right
   [image]

After this you are good to go. Then, if you want to refine your configuration, you can use the "Administrative Roles" tab to set the command that can be used by the user (SELECT, ALTER etc etc) and the "Schema privileges" tab to restrict the user interaction to specific schemas.

Answer (score 7):

Just use the interface provided by MySql's GUI Tool (SQLyog):

Click on User manager:
[image]

Now, if you want to grant access FOR ANY OTHER REMOTE PC, just make sure that, just like in the underneath picture, the Host field value is % (which is the wildcard)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Most of the answers here show you creating users with two host values: one for `localhost`, and one for `%`.

Please note that except for a built-in localhost user like root, you don't need to do this. If you simply want to make a new user that can log in from anywhere, you can use

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
GRANT <whatever privileges are appropriate> ON <relevant tables> TO myuser;
```

and it will work just fine. (As others have mentioned, it's a terrible idea to grant administrative privileges to a user from any domain.)

Answer (score 4):

Well, nothing of the above answer worked for me. After a lot of research, I found a solution. Though I may be late this may help others in future.

Login to your SQL server from a terminal

```sql
 mysql -u root -p
 -- root password
GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'XX.XXX.XXX.XX' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

This should solve the permission issue.

[image: Before solving error]

[image: After solving issue]

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 3):

simple way is to login to phpmyadmin with root account , there goto mysql database and select user table , there edit root account and in host field add % wild card . and then through ssh flush privileges

```
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: This helped me combined with this: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing same issue, It resolved in 2 min for me i just white list ip through cpanel

Suppose you are trying to connect database of server B from server A.
Go to Server B Cpanel->Remote MySQL-> enter Server A IP Address and That's it.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a recent mysql install, then before changing anything else, try simply to execute this command and then try again:

```
flush privileges;
```

This alone fixes the issue for me on Ubuntu 16.04, mysql 5.7.20. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

Just find a better way to do that from your hosting control panel (I'm using DirectAdmin here)

simply go to the target server DB in your control panel, in my case:
MySQL management -> select your DB -> you will find: "Access Hosts", simply add your remote host here and its working now!
[image]

I guess there is a similar option on other C.panels like plesk, etc..

I'm hope it was helpful to you too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allow users from other locations(x.x.x.x in your case) as well from where you are going to connect to the database.

All the above answers do seem correct in the wildcard(%) declaration for allowing hosts from all locations but that opens it to all hosts and hence opening a **security risk**. Its better to explicitly specify the host as follows:

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'x.x.x.x' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'x.x.x.x' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Replace x.x.x.x with the host ip that you are connecting from.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be running on Windows; A simple solution is to run the MySQL server instance configuration wizard.  It is in your MYSQL group in the start menu.  On the second from last screen click the box that says "allow root access from remote machines".

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

this error because no password to the root , and this Maybe occurred with you when you trying to connect from outside  .

Answer (score 1):

If you have WAMP Server + Windows 10 and you are using it for development than Right Click on Wamp Icon => `Wamp Settings` => `Check Allow Virtual Hosts other than 127*`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**1. From a terminal, connect you to your MySQL running container**

```
docker exec -it your_container_name_or_id bash
```

**2.  In your container, connect you to the MySQL database**

```
mysql -u your_user -p
```

enter your password to connect to database.

**3. execute this SQL script to list all existing database users:**

```
SELECT host, user FROM mysql.user;
```

The result will be some thing like below:

| host | user |
| --- | --- |
| 127.0.0.1 | root |
| ::1 | root |
| localhost | mysql.sys |
| localhost | root |

you should add a new row:

| host | user |
| --- | --- |
| % | root |

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well what you can do is just open mysql.cfg file and you have to change Bind-address to this

**bind-address      = 127.0.0.1**

and then Restart mysql and you will able to connect that server to this.

Look this you can have idea form that.

[this is real sol](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html)

Comment: This is related, but not the same problem. The error originally received indicates the client is connecting to the MySQL server successfully, but then failing authentication. If bind-address was set to 127.0.0.1, you would get a connection refused error instead.

Comment: But this is address which will allow all the Host to get connected to the server na?

Comment: But Granting all the permission to the user will not be wise option for that bcoz if u have client user and u are not allowed to create user with all permission then what would be the Solution.?

Answer (score 0):

This answer might help someone...

All these answers didnt help, then I realised I forgot to check one crucial thing.. The port :)

I have mysql running in a docker container running on a different port. I was pointing to my host machine on port 3306, which I have a mysql server running on. My container exposes the server on port 33060. So all this time, i was looking at the wrong server! doh!

Answer (score 0):

This working for **DirectAdmin**;

1. Go to your `DirectAdmin`.
2. Go to your `MySQL Management`.
3. Select your `database`.
4. Under your `Accesse Host` tab,  there is a field. 
    You should fill this field by `xxx.xx.xxx.xx`.
5. Click on `Add Host`.

Finished. Now you can access to this DB by your `your_database_username` & `your_database_password`.
**So Simple!**

Answer (score 0):

CPANEL solution

Go to Cpanel, look for Remote MySQL. 
Add the the IP in the input field:

Host (% wildcard is allowed)

Comment to remember what IP that is. 
That was it for me.

Answer (score -1):

**Some tips:**

- **list privileges** using `show grants;`
- **create a VPN** and just add the ip of the tunnel

Answer (score -2):

if you are trying to execute mysql query withouth defining connectionstring, you will get this error.

Probably you forgat to define connection string before execution. have you check this out?
(sorry for bad english)

Answer (score -2):

Problem: root@localhost is unable to connect to a fresh installation of mysql-community-server on openSUSE 42.2-1.150.x86_64.
Mysql refuses connections - period.

Solution:

```
$ ls -l /var/lib/mysql/mysql/user.*
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql     0 Apr 29 19:44 /var/lib/mysql/mysql/user.MYD
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  1024 Apr 29 19:44 /var/lib/mysql/mysql/user.MYI
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 10684 Apr 29 19:44 /var/lib/mysql/mysql/user.frm
```

**File user.MYD has 0 size** (really ?!).
I copied all 3 files from another working system.

```
$ /usr/sbin/rcmysql stop
$ cd /var/lib/mysql/mysql/
$ scp root@othersytem:/var/lib/mysql/mysql/user.* ./
$ /usr/sbin/rcmysql start
$ cd -
$ mysql -u root -p
```

I was able to log in. Then, it was just a matter of re-applying all schema privileges.
Also, if you disabled IPv6, re-enable it temporary so that root@::1 account  can also work.

Answer (score -6):

All of the answers here didn't work in my case so I guest this may help other users in the future. This can also be a problem in our code, not just in MySQL alone.

If you are using `VB.NET`

Instead of this code:

```
 Dim server As String = My.Settings.DB_Server
 Dim username As String = My.Settings.DB_Username
 Dim password As String = My.Settings.DB_Password
 Dim database As String = My.Settings.DB_Database

 MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=" & server & ";" _
 & "user id=" & username & ";" _
 & "password=" & password & ";" _
 & "database=" & database

 MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection()
```

You need to move `MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection()` on the first line. So it would be like this

```
 MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection()

 Dim server As String = My.Settings.DB_Server
 Dim username As String = My.Settings.DB_Username
 Dim password As String = My.Settings.DB_Password
 Dim database As String = My.Settings.DB_Database

 MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=" & server & ";" _
 & "user id=" & username & ";" _
 & "password=" & password & ";" _
 & "database=" & database
```

Comment: Read the question properly first before answering. Your answer is unrelated and does not help at all!