# trying to connect to mysql and getting error :is not allowed to connect to this MySQL serverConnection closed by foreign host

Tags: mysql

Hi i am running two rhel instances in ec2.
now i am trying to do
 $telnet ec2-184-73-58-163.compute-1.amazonaws.com 3306

```
Trying 10.193.139.147...
Connected to ec2-184-73-58-163.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
bHost 'domU-12-31-39-05-3D-E6.compute-1.internal' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL serverConnection closed by foreign host.
```

I am a newbie. not getting what to do now?
Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You cannot connect to the remote MySQL if you are not white listed in the MySQL user privileges table.

---

Let's assume your IP address is `199.255.209.168` and you are trying to log into the MySQL daemon running at IP address `123.238.18.47` by the username `rakman` with some password

```
$ mysql -h 123.238.18.47 -u rakman -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '199.255.209.168' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

A mysql user [rakman]@[your IP address] needs to be present in the user privileges of MySQL running at `123.238.18.47`. So `rakman@199.255.209.168` (or `rakman@%` which will allow logging in to this MySQL from ANY remote host but is not recommended) needs to be present in the user privileges of MySQL running at `123.238.18.47`.

For the MySQL commands on how to achieve this, you can see the accepted answer at [Host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server). If you try to login after that.

```
$ mysql -h 123.238.18.47 -u rakman -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.
```

Answer (score 18):

You have to give access permission on mysql .

To create a new user:

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'youripaddres' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

for all ips use below

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

for particular ip use below

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'youripaddres' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

p.s. `flush privileges;` is needed to take changes into effect.

Answer (score 2):

I am also not that good in this area but i think this link can help you a little. 
This was my reference when i was having trouble with MySQL.

just try. I hope it works.
[SourceForge.net](http://nst.sourceforge.net/nst/docs/faq/ch06s04.html)