# MySQLdb error 1130: Not getting the correct IP of the server

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm trying to connect to mysqldb through a python script. I have changed the bind-address in my.cnf to '192.168.56.101' which is my server ip.

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host='192.168.56.101',
                     user='root',
                     passwd='pass',
                     db='python')
```

the above code gives me following error.

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1130, "Host '192.168.56.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server")
```

It has taken my ip '192.168.56.101' as '192.168.56.1'?
Also I tried this:

```
mysql -u nilani -p pass -h 192.168.56.101
```

It also giving the same kind of error,

```
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '192.168.56.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL serve
```

Why it cannot identify my ip correctly?

Comment: Have you `pinged` it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a lack of permissions on the server side.

MySQL doesn't allow root users to connect from other machines on the network. the IP `192.168.56.1` is probably your own machine's IP.

In order to create a user that can log from other machines, refer to this question: [Host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)

It involves creating a separate user for localhost and remote host access on the server (taken from linked question):

```sql
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
```