# Message from Server: "Host '192.168.169.98' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Using JDBC, I am currently trying to connect to a server hosted on the same network using MAMP.

Using this string: `private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.169.101:8889/";`

I received this error: `message from server: "Host '192.168.169.98' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"`

I am wondering if this is a firewall error?

Comment: can you login the server with `youruser@192.168.169.98` ?

Comment: I made a mistake, but host number is 8888. My mistake!

Comment: Are you trying to do remote connection? If so, you need to give Remote priviliges.

Comment: @Nambari Yes. I am connecting from a Windows machine to a MAMP server hosted right beside me. Same network.

Comment: You need to grant permisions. This may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server

Answer (score 1):

Comment out 'skip-networking' in your my.cnf file.

If skip-networking is commented out, then it's a user level permission which needs to be set in the mysql.user or mysql.database tables.

Comment: If you're just testing:

MYSQL> USE mysql
MYSQL> update user set Host="%" WHERE 1=1

That'll remove all restrictions from all users.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL wants you to GRANT permission for users to connect to the server by IP address and credentials.  I think it's a good idea to set up credentials for that particular database and user and GRANT only the permissions necessary to accomplish the task.

*Don't* use the root admin credentials for anything except administration.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

Comment: It's simply a test database. I will definitely be implementing precautions on a live one.

Comment: First we make our habits, then our habits make us.  Do the right thing, even for a test database.