# How to remove this bug while making jdbc simple program

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

[image]
Hi
I am making simple program of getting data from data base .I download sql for mac and insert schema , then table and entry .So I need to retrieve data from data base .I am using mysql .
I also insert conector jar of mysql .
[image]
I do like that 
import java.sql.*;

```
![public class FirstExample {
   // JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Database";

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "";
   static final String PASS = "";

   public static void main(String\[\] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

      //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      String sql;
      sql = "SELECT id, name, age FROM Employee";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

      //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
      while(rs.next()){
         //Retrieve by column name
         int id  = rs.getInt("id");
         int age = rs.getInt("age");
         String first = rs.getString("name");
        // String last = rs.getString("last");

         //Display values
         System.out.print("ID: " + id);
         System.out.print(", Age: " + age);
         System.out.print(", First: " + first);
     //    System.out.println(", Last: " + last);
      }
      //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      //finally block used to close resources
      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }// nothing we can do
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
   }//end try
   System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}//end main
}//end FirstExample][3]





Connecting to database...
Goodbye!
java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host '192.168.1.100' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1086)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1114)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2493)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2311)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at FirstExample.main(FirstExample.java:21)
```

Comment: You haven't set permissions on your MySQL server.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis If you convert your comment to an answer, I will upvote it.

Comment: how to set permission

Comment: @DavidWallace I don't have the details on how to set those permissions. I don't want to post incomplete answers :(

Comment: please guys tell how to set permission

Comment: As @SotiriosDelimanolis said you need to set up permissions for your MySQL instance. In MySQL Workbench go to the "Server" menu heading and select "Users and Privileges". You can add a user here by clicking the"Add Account" button in the bottom left of the screen.

Comment: At least make some effort and look it up yourself.

Comment: jdbc:mysql://localhost/Database here you did not mention mysql server port. mysql by default run on 3306 port. so is your mysql running on 3306 or 80 port?

Comment: there is no option of server . Workbench

Comment: you can use `mysql` command line client if nothing else and enter these commands - fix username and other variables.

Comment: Is this actually a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server ?

Answer (score 2):

Your DB user is not allowed to connect to your MySQL server. In MySQL (strangely) there is something like a firewall and access is defined per user per host. You need to connect to MySQL via any SQL client and give access:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

For example a bit too broad access but should work:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

If you didn't create a user first:

```
CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
```

Comment: why you copy and paste answer from another thread rather give the link as comment.

Comment: In general procedure is: login as root to mysql, create db, create app user and grant privs to him, grant connect to your MySQL server host. Done.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server

Comment: yes it's copied from MySQL docs that's why 'monty' is in both answers. I didn't search for answers on SO I just answered because I know.