# host is not allowed to connect to this server

Tags: php, mysql

quick mysql question.
I'm new at php/mysql and followed a tutorial(php/mysql for dummies) so I don't really know what I did wrong or if the tutorial is wrong.

I have a file, "database_connections.inc", that looks like this:

```
<?php
$user = "username";
$host = "host";
$password = "password";
$database = "database";
?>
```

With the actual credentials not included for obvious reasons.

Then in another file, login.php, I have:

```
include("database_connections.inc");
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database)
or die("Query died: Couldnt connect to server.");
```

I get an error message with the "or die" text, accompanied by a warning:

> host xxxxx.000webhost.com is not allowed to connect to this mysql server in....

Why not?  I'm sure my credentials are all correct.

I've read in a few places to run some shell statements...but can't really do that, I'm on Windows.

I'm using phpMyAdmin, so hopefully I can do something from there?

Comment: Most MySQL servers are configured that they only accept local connections, so unless your `$host` is `localhost`, it probably won’t work. This is for security reasons btw. and unless you have really good reasons, and a good security system, you shouldn’t change that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)

Comment: Where is your code running at and where is the database at?

Comment: http://www.techdreams.org/mysql-database-server/fixing-the-error-host-xxxxxxxxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server/2240-20090411

Comment: Host should be `xxxxx.000webhost.com` and not "host" or "localhost". I am familiar with that server.

Answer (score 1):

Open "database_connections.inc" and change it to look like this:

```
<?php
$user = "root";
$host = "localhost";
$password = "";
$database = "test";
?>
```

MySQL is by default configured to work with localhost (or 127.0.0.1), in order to allow "host xxxxx.000webhost.com" as host, open phpMyAdmin and select "SQL" and execute this query;

```
GRANT ALL ON your_database_name.* TO your_user@your_host_xx.xxx.xx.xx IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';
```

Answer (score 0):

Go into PHPMyAdmin, and edit your user.

Under Login Information, there should be an option for "Host"- try adding `xxxxx.000webhost.com`.