# Host '127.x.x.x' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, openshift

After I deploy my php app to OpenShift it works without an issue for some time. Then suddenly, few hours later it throws "Host not allowed to connect to this MySQL server" error. If I delete MySQL cartridge and reinstall again, it will work again for some time. What may cause this error? I sshed to my app and run

```
mysql
```

it still shows the same error: Host '127.x.x.x' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server

Comment: Not related at all, but it is no use "redacting" 127.0.0.1, since it is not accessible from outside your machine, being the loopback address ;)

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/hack-127001 :)