# MySQL Access Denied despite user setup correctly to allow outside connection

Tags: mysql

I have a user setup to allow outside connections using % access.

Despite that, I get the error

Host blk-x-x-x.isp.com is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.

Comment: Have you flushed priviledges or restarted mysql after setting up the `user@%`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)

Comment: I have one user, root@% and thats it, cant connect.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your mysql isn't setup to listen on a TCP port.

In your my.cnf file are you configured to run via socket or TCP port?  If socket only, the only local clients can connect to it. Find the port you're on with (assuming you can execute a query, if not assume it's port 3306):

```
show global variables like "port";
```

Then check your server to see if that port is actually open.  Assuming it's 3306, you'd do this on the command line if you're on unix based system, on windows I'm not sure:

```
  netstat -tln | grep 3306
```

If nothing shows up, you're not listing on any port.

Comment: @Wilson is youre server on you local machine?

Comment: is there something i can look for in my config file

Comment: @Wilson you need to figure out on windows how to find what ports are open and listening.   I think it's somethign like `netstat -a | find "LISTENING"`

Comment: @Wilson  if you're setup to use a port there will be a line like `port=3306` in your my.cnf (or my.ini) file.  Otherwise there will be a line like `socket=/some/path/to/socket`

Comment: I found out that the port is 3306.

Comment: @Wilson did your nestat show something listening on that port?

Comment: Yes, TCP 3306 is listening

Comment: I'd like to note to im trying to connect directly through my IP on another computer on my network. When I dont use localhost, even on the PC running mySQL, it gives me the same error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52333/discussion-between-ray-and-wilson)