# Host is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server for client-server application

Tags: mysql

I just exported my tables from one web host to another (AWS).
Thinking everything would go smoothly (yeah right), well, everything that can go wrong has gone wrong.

I get this error when trying to query my database (which I didn't get before):

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host '<my ip address>' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server`

This is the same error from this post:

[Host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)

The solution in that post seems to revolve around having an administrative user.    I am developing a chat application so every user needs to access the server (so I'm sure it's a bad idea to give them all administrative privileges).
The answer by Pascal in that link says, `If you are using mysql for a client/server application, prefer a subnet address.` but I honestly don't understand what he means by that.  And because of the amount of solutions, I'm not exactly sure which one I should follow based on my case.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Let mysqld listen on 0.0.0.0:3306

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has security tables that determine who is allowed to connect and from what host IP address.

Here's a good article on how to do it:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

If you have a lot of connections, consider setting up a server to accept the connections and talk to the sql server.  The easiest approach to this is to set up a REST interface and use a web server.  Web servers are usually also highly optimized and relatively bug free.

In a similar architecture on AWS, I use nginx happily.

Comment: Hey Charlie, I was able to connect to my mysql server using:
`$ mysql -u webadmin –h myElasticIpAddress` but this scared the crap out of me because this means anyone with my ip can easily start manipulating the data.  I don't have anything important at the moment, but this obviously isn't ideal.  Since users themselves don't have to issue commands (I just send their input to my php scripts and the scripts on the server handle the queries), should I just remove any query priveleges? I'm pretty confused at this step.

Comment: Accepted this answer because the answer below told me I had to add a user when I did not.  And although both answers referred me to the same link (which was very helpful), this answer was posted first.
Oh and FINALLYY! My app can connect to the server and all is well!!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have `bind-address=YOUR-SERVER-IP` in my.cnf and make sure you have a user `hd1@172.31.39.86` or `hd1@%`, the latter being a MySQL wildcard on the MySQL server. More information [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html). You may also need to grant access to port 3306 (the default MySQL port) on the security groups section of the AWS console.

Comment: I followed the link you both referred me to and the only thing I haven't done is add in that user.  
I have a user `%` with the following properties:
`User: Any, Host %, Password: --, Global Privileges: Usage, Grant: No`.
Should I change the Grant to `yes`?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you told me to put a user hd1@172.31.39.86 when that's your username...? lol

Answer (score 0):

```
// IN YOUR MYSQL WORKBENCH You Have to Execute below query

CREATE USER 'root'@'1.2.1.5(Your Application Server IP)' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'10.200.1.54' WITH GRANT OPTION;

AFTER CREATING YOU CAN VIEW USING BELOW QUERY

SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'root';
```