# sqlalchemy connect to VPS database

Tags: python, mysql, ssh, sqlalchemy

I am trying to connect to VPS mysql database from my PC. I use sqlalchemy framework, but I need establish SSH tunnel before connection.

Usual way, when web app run on VPS:

```
create_engine('mysql://user:pswd@localhost/dbname')
```

How can I connect to this database from another PC. Assume there are connections credentials: IP, username, password

Comment: What happens when you replace `localhost` with the IP address of the database server?

Comment: When I pass IP with SSH port 22: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0") None None

Comment: And with mysql port 3306: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (111)") None None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MySQL server is listening to local connections only. To make it listen to outside connections:

1. Edit the `/etc/mysl/my.cnf` file
2. Comment out the line `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`
3. Restart `mysqld`

Comment: It was uncommented. I think that I have to connect to VPS through SSH tunnel but I do not know how.

Comment: You should **comment** it if it is uncommented.

Comment: after 'create_engine('mysql://mysql_username:mysql_pswd@IP:3306/db_name')' : **sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1130, "Host 'bband-dyn233.178-41-4.t-com.sk' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server") None None**

Comment: This is another (privilege) problem. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server