# Python connection to server and interact with database

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server

I have question how can I connect to VPS server and interact with MySQL database using python on my local machine.

I would like to make program using PyQT that connect to my server and update, take sth from db.

I know that there is MySQLdb module but from what I know i cannot connect to VPS server, because in connect method it doesn't take server password argument.

Comment: you can take help from following link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476926/sqlalchemy-connect-to-vps-database