# MySQL federated host "my ip" is not allowed to connect mysql server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, federated-table

I've confused about this problem, and still stuck out of it for a week.
I've trying to federated table in mysql, but when tried to do query select to remote table. I got this message

> > Error Code: 1429. Unable to connect to foreign data source: Host '172.25.97.136' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

while 172.25.97.136 is my ip static address not remote server's ip address

i've read this solution [Host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server) But still didn't work.

anyone can help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check, are you able to connect to that mentioned ip using mysql as,

mysql -hXX.XX.XX.XX -u -p

If you are unable to login with above command,clearly it is a permissions issue.

Please check.

Thanks,
Lakshmi