# MySQL - VB - Connection Error ReportViewer

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, report

I'm doing a report with a report viewer form.

And returns me a error when i try to open the connection.

Here's the error:

```
 MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException occurred

  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=Authentication to host '' for user '' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user ''@'fe80::289c:18c7:6714:8608%2' (using password: NO)

Inner Exception 1:
MySqlException: Access denied for user ''@'fe80::289c:18c7:6714:8608%2' (using password: NO)
```

All the other connections goes well but this one.

Error on code:

```
myAdapter.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Stock", conn)

myAdapter.Fill(dbDataSet.Tables(0))
```

Connection:

```
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
        conn = New MySqlConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=;database=Empresa;"
```

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Already tried this one ([Host xxxx is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672480/host-xxxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)) but now the error changes to this.

Apreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You security is not quite right.  Mysql allows / defaults to bind a user to an address.   See the below:

https://serverfault.com/q/257513/219898

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3552946/1662973

If it is local ONLY, you can also consider turning off IPV6 - I see that it is binding to that.

Comment: Network adapter settings - there is a checkbox.  Leave IPV4 alone, but untick IPV6.

Comment: Thank you. It works but now tells me this: "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'No database selected'"

Comment: Make sure the user has access to the database.  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';