# Cannot connect to MySQL on server - #1130

Tags: mysql

There have been a number of questions on this topic on Stackoverflow but not exactly my situation.

I have a MySQL server installed on my PC, which was working fine. We used to have a peer-to-peer network in the office. My PC was just named "MY-PC". Some change occurred to the network and my PC is now connected to a "proper" network, and the name of the PC has changed to "MY-PC.mycompanywebsite.co.uk".

Now every time I try to connect to MySQL it gives me the error:

```
#1130 - Host 'My-PC.mycompanywebsite.co.uk' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

I can't log in using the command line tool or anything. Is there a config file setting I need to change to get this working?

By the way, this is a version of MySQL which came in an installation of WAMPServer, so I did not configure it myself.

Comment: Are you sure it's not answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server ?

Comment: Yes, because I can't even connect at all using the mysql command line tool. Most other questions seem to be about granting access to remote users, but I can't even access mysql on the server...

Comment: Have you tried the solutions from that question? The issue you're having is that yourname@my-pc has permission in mysql, while yourname@my-pc.mycompanywebsite.co.uk does not have permission. (or, possibly, %@my-pc has permission, while %@my-pc.mycompanywebsite.co.uk does not, which comes to the same thing). Mysql is issuing the error, your mysql command-line command is, technically connecting. The problem is authentication.