# SqlConnectionStringBuilder using wrong data

Tags: c#, sql

So I'm using a connection string from my app.config file to connect to my database. I also tried to make it more secure, so that my SqlCOnnectionStringBuilder retrieves its info from the app.config file. To give you a better idea of what I mean here's some code:

app.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <clear/>
  <add name="connection"
       connectionString="Data Source=SERVERIP; Initial Catalog=DB; 
                        Port=3306; User ID=USERNAME; Password=PASSWORD;"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Method for the connection builder:

```
    private void BuildConnectionString()
    {
        ConnectionStringSettings settings = 
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"];

        if (null != settings)
        {
            MySqlConnectionStringBuilder builder =
                new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder(settings.ConnectionString);

            conString = builder.ConnectionString;
        }
    }
```

Somehow the user id gets replaced with the name of my computer, which is very wierd since the IP, port and the initial catalog aren't being replaced.

Oh and [I followed this handy article here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254947(v=vs.110).aspx).

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT:
Here is the full error I'm getting:

> An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Host 'nameofpc' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

Comment: I don't use MySql, but the problem could be that your connection string is using the MSSQL provider. Try using the correct provider or just put the string in a regular appSetting instead of connectionStrings section.

Comment: What o you mean Crowcoder? and stuartd, that didn't do much

Comment: @B.Hulshof, why do you even need the builder? It seems redundant. Try just `conString = settings.ConnectionString;`

Comment: I thought that the ConnectionStringBuilder was some sort of extra security?

Comment: @B.Hulshof, a builder is for creating a connection string but you already have one.

Comment: Ah ok thank you! I've added the error to my question to make it a bit more clear

Comment: @B.Hulshof, in that case it is an environmental issue, meaning your code is not the problem. Do you have a database administrator?

Comment: Yes, that'd be me.

Comment: Have you fixed the provider name in your app.config yet. As @stuartd said you need to use MySql.Data.MySqlClient. You are currently using a Microsoft SQL Server provider.

Comment: Yes I did, no success.

Comment: @B.Hulshof Did the error remain the same? Your connection string seems to be for Microsoft SQL Server too. I dont think "Initial Catalog" is a MySQL property.

Comment: It worked fine before when I used it outside of the app.config, but the app.config is more secure

Comment: And yes the error remained the same

Comment: No luck so far, anybody know a solution?

Comment: I tried everything you guys told me and still not even one single good result.

Answer (score -2):

It seems to me that the problem is that the MariaDB server is only accepting incoming connections from a certain set of hosts. Most likely the server is defaulted to accept only localhost connections. I think that this link might be helpful: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/.

Comment: How is this answer direspectful or off topic to deserve downvoting when the error he's getting points exactly to the cause I mentioned?

Comment: I tried editting the user settings, which didn't work. And the server accepts every connection so it isn't that. this is not "exactly" pointing to the cause of the error.

Comment: Are you able to connect with that user from a different machine?

Comment: What's on the host column for the user that you trying to connect with?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111764/discussion-between-zalomon-and-b-hulshof).

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1559992/43846) regarding the host column wildcard