# Change XXX host on error: "Host XXX is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server, reverse-dns

When connecting to mysql server, I receive the error "Host XXX is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server". So, I want to change the XXX host name to another more understandable because the name is too long, and I want to configure a mysql user like: "user@understandable-host-name"

My OS is ubuntu 16.04 Server

---

Edit: please, dont confuse my ask with connections problems. I am connecting successfully. I only want to know HOW TO CHANGE **XXX** HOST NAME.

Doesnt work changing neither /etc/hosts nor /etc/hostname

I think is something related about rDNS, but I dont know how to change the name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)

Comment: @SsJVasto I've edited my question. Is not about connection problem, but rDNS.