# Connection failed: Host 'linux547.grserver.gr' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

Tags: database-connection, mariadb

[code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5DvA.jpg)  i am trying to connect my site to a database using this code:

but I get this error:

Connection failed: Host 'linux547.grserver.gr' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Dont put an image of the code. Put the relevant code. Please go through this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)