# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql

It is the first time I upload a web page to a server and I am quite inexperienced in the subject.
I downloaded xampp to work in a production environment and through phpmyadmin I configured a user name, password and host = '%'
But when I upload my files with Filezila, I throw this:

> SQLSTATE [HY000] [1045] Access denied for 'user' @ 'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

I tried to connect to my server through the Mysql Shell and Workbench to create a user "user" that had all the permissions to access my database, but in both cases I threw the following:

> Host xxxx.xx.xx Is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server.

What I do not understand is why MariaDB Server? I do not have it downloaded or something.

I do not really know how I can grant the permissions to the new user inside the host so that it can access my database. My connection code is as follows:

```
try {   
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=%;dbname=db_name;charset=utf8';
    $db = new PDO($dsn, 'user', 'contraseña');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

Comment: is your mysql on the same server?

Comment: Try and change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 2):

1)For the first error, it is saying  that your mysql credentials are invalid. Correct your database configuration in your php code. Arrange the username, password, etc... You can get this info from your hosting provider. Try to change '%' to 'localhost'.

2)For the second
[Host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server) and

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have changed the username, and password (those provided by my hosting provider) in phpmyadmin, in the console (the second problem is solved, thanks!) and in my php code, and I have left both the host as localhost, but the error persists.

Comment: @Michael, edit your answer to prevent clogging up the comment replies on your answer.

Comment: `ALTER USER 'userName'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'New-Password-Here';` helped since I did not set a password. then grant privileges and flush.

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue:If your server name is localhost. Please verify all o f the info (servername, username, password for database) from your hosting provider. Try this code:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "yourusername";
$password = "yourpassword";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=yourdatabase", 
    $username, $password);
   // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB is a fork of MySQL, many hosting providers and linux distributions have MariaDB by default. Using MariaDB is quite the same as MySQL. Note that in your connection string the host is typically `localhost` instead of `%`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I named my environment variable USER for database user, which by default picks the operating system Username so instead I renamed my database user to MYSQL_USER, just a name different from USER. Then I was able to access it with process.env.MYSQL_USER.
If I try to access it initially with process.env.USER, it picks my OS username instead of the set mysql database username.