# Error establishing a database connection - Setting up Wordpress on AWS ec2 instance

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to set up wordpress on my ec2 instance on AWS, following the instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html).

I have wordpress installed and unzipped, and was at the point where I needed to set up my database.

In my ec2 instance, all my wordpress files are in `/var/www/html`...they are no longer inside a folder called 'wordpress', though.

In my `wp-config.php` file, I have my database name, password, and salts all set. I also ran `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON`wordpress-db`.* TO "wordpress-user"@"ip-XXX-XX-XXX";` (where wordpress-db, wordpress-user are my correct names, and I'm using the ip for my database's hostname value).

I've tried rebooting my instance, starting and stopping it, and have checked that mysql and httpd are running, but I still can't connect to the database! Am I missing something?! Any leads would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: If you're using and ip then `"wordpress-user"@"localhost"` won't work.

Comment: Ah-- I think I actually did run that again with the ip...let me try that again though, just to be sure.

Comment: OK, yes, I did run it with the ip...sorry for the confusion. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Also is the server listening on all interfaces `0.0.0.0`? else that won't work.

Comment: Yes-- I have `0.0.0.0/0`

Comment: Referer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24171107/661872

Comment: It's working now! I think I just needed to create a new user and grant different admin privileges, per what some of the suggestions in that SO post suggested...thank you for sending!