# maria DB connection issue

Tags: mariadb, talend, mysql-error-1064

I am facing below issue when cconnecting to mariaDb through Talend

```
Exception in component tMysqlConnection_2
java.sql.SQLException: Host 'xx.xx.xx.xx' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.get(SQLExceptionMapper.java:149)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.throwException(SQLExceptionMapper.java:106)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:114)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at local_project.bokka_0_1.bokka.tMysqlConnection_2Process(bokka.java:321)
    at local_project.bokka_0_1.bokka.runJobInTOS(bokka.java:586)
    at local_project.bokka_0_1.bokka.main(bokka.java:443)
Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.common.QueryException: Host '10.207.0.39' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.mysql.MySQLProtocol.connect(MySQLProtocol.java:398)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.mysql.MySQLProtocol.connect(MySQLProtocol.java:673)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.mysql.MySQLProtocol.<init>(MySQLProtocol.java:266)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:110)
    ... 5 more
```

Could someone help me resolve this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)

Comment: I suppose rights issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for responses, This was a firewall issue with target machine.

Disabled the same and everything worked fine