# mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect my local PHP program from one PC and Mysql from a server or another PC. But I got following error when I tried this

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in D:\xampp\htdocs\bharat\bharat\connect.php
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in D:\xampp\htdocs\bharat\bharat\connect.php
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in D:\xampp\htdocs\bharat\bharat\connect.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('https://192.168.43.215', 'root', '12345678', 'bharat') or die(mysqli_error("Error connection"));
```

I tried to keep mysql database in remote server for data security and software in local machine. Can any one tell me the exact way. Thank you.

Comment: That's because `https://192.168.43.215` is not a hostname, it's a URL. Get rid of the protocol and try again.

Comment: Do not add `https://` to the db host. It needs to be just the ip or hostname.

Comment: What can be the hostname ? Can you tell me the way..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `https://`, this would be sufficient:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('192.168.43.215', 'root', '12345678', 'bharat') or die(mysqli_error("Error connection"));
```

Comment: Did this but it shows                                                                                                 Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host 'Ajoy-PC' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server in D:\xampp\htdocs\bharat\bharat\connect.php on line 5

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in D:\xampp\htdocs\bharat\bharat\connect.php on line 5

Comment: when I try to connect with my hosting server                              mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'bharatmain'@'47.29.226.179' (using password: YES)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server