# How to access MySQL Local Server, Error Class File Editor when use dynamic ip to change localhost

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have some issue when trying to make an election application (Java and Eclipse Luna IDE) using my laptop as server and other as client. I'm also using phpMyAdmin database from XAMPP.

It's working when I use localhost and 127.0.0.1 ip as the address.

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db", "root", "")
```

and

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db", "root", "")
```

The problem is when I access this server still using my laptop, but change the address to my dynamic WI-FI IP address, it caught on errors.

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.11:3306/db", "root", "")
```

The errors I've got is Class File editor--source not found just like these

[MysqlIO.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh8lk.png) [Connectionlmpl.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQbV3.png)

Both of those errors require me to select the location of `mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar`, but I've already download and attach the file into package [(like this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgInD.png) and it keeps give me those errors.

I've already googled for editing `my.cnf` files to delete the **bind-address**, but in my case I can't found `my.cnf` file, only `my.ini` file that exist, so I only edit `my.ini` file by deleting the bind-address code.

Could somebody help me with this problems? I cannot find out the solution,

I've just tried to test the connection using this code

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.11:3306/db";
String username = "root";
String password = "";

System.out.println("Connecting database...");

try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)) {
    System.out.println("Database connected!");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot connect the database!", e);
}
```

The result is

```
> Connecting database...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot connect the database!
    at election.ElectionApp.main(ElectionApp.java:251)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host 'MyComputer.local' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1040)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2191)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly    (ConnectionImpl.java:2222)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2017)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:779)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at Election.ElectionApp.main(ElectionApp.java:248)
```

Comment: I think the problem is about security. This link may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server

Comment: The errors in your screenshot are just Eclipse who can't find the sources from MySQL. You're likely debugging or otherwise jumping to a line in the MySQL implementation. Your actual problem seems to be one of MySQL configuration or user authorization.