# Access to Virtual machine MySQL database from windows host with python

Tags: python, mysql, server, virtual-machine

I´m trying to connect to a mysql database installed on a virtual machine with Ubuntu Server. I´m very new to server administration so I followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lamp-on-ubuntu-18-04) LAMP on it. I also followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-18-04) to install phpMyAdmin. Apparently, everything is working fine. I can access to phpMyAdmin from the web browser on my host machine.

The network of the virtual machine is configured as bridge adapter.

The problem is that I cannot connect when using python (also from host machine). This is the code I'm using:

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='XXXXX',
                              host='192.168.1.138',
                              port=3306,
                              database='mysql')
cnx.close()
```

The code returns this error:

```
DatabaseError: 1130: Host 'desktop-p7v30jj.home' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

I looked for information and found that it could be due to the bind-address. So I edited the file `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf` and included the following two lines at the end with no success:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

What else should I try? Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the solution by simply creating another user, as stated in this topic:
[Host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)

Sorry for answering.

Regards.