# Spring Boot, MySQL, Tomcat can't create intital connections of pool in Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, spring-boot, tomcat

I have created a webapp using Spring Boot and REST APIs in Eclipse. When I try to run it using Tomcat 8, it gives the error 
**"o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool: Unable to create initial connections of pool."**

I tried using the solutions provided but nothing seemed to work, it always gives the same error.

This is my application.properties file -

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbase?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = 1234
spring.datasource.password = 1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

and this is the pom.xml file -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.springboot</groupId>
  <artifactId>springbootrestapi</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>springbootrestapiexample Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>       
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>springbootrestapiexample</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

This is the stack trace -

```
16:33:43.182 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
16:33:43.206 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/]
16:33:43.207 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/C:/Users/Amber%20Bhanarkar/eclipse-workspace/springbootrestapi/target/classes/]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.4.RELEASE)

2019-05-29 16:33:43.767  INFO 13396 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.s.StudentApplication                 : Starting StudentApplication on LAPTOP-BV6107FE with PID 13396 (started by Amber Bhanarkar in C:\Users\Amber Bhanarkar\eclipse-workspace\springbootrestapi)
2019-05-29 16:33:43.768  INFO 13396 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.s.StudentApplication                 : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-05-29 16:33:43.892  INFO 13396 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@754391d8: startup date [Wed May 29 16:33:43 IST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-05-29 16:33:49.463  INFO 13396 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-05-29 16:33:49.552  INFO 13396 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-05-29 16:33:49.554  INFO 13396 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.15
2019-05-29 16:33:50.076  INFO 13396 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-05-29 16:33:50.076  INFO 13396 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6188 ms
2019-05-29 16:33:50.354  INFO 13396 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2019-05-29 16:33:50.359  INFO 13396 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-05-29 16:33:50.360  INFO 13396 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2019-05-29 16:33:50.360  INFO 13396 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2019-05-29 16:33:50.360  INFO 13396 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2019-05-29 16:33:55.529 ERROR 13396 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

Here is StudentApplication.java -

```
package com.springboot.springbootrestapi;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class StudentApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StudentApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add full stack trace of your error?

Comment: is your MySQL service running in background ?

Comment: @TechatTheSparksFoundation how do I check that? I have the MySQL command line client, should that be running in background?

Comment: goto `start -> run` , type `services.msc` press enter . look for a service named `mysqld` and its status should be running.

Comment: @TechatTheSparksFoundation instead of mysqld there is MySQL80 and it is in running state and the startup type is automatic.

Comment: For `MySQL8.0` you are suggested to use `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect` as dialect in `application.properties` , try it and see if it resolves your problem

Comment: @TechatTheSparksFoundationNo it didn't resolve the error. There are some errors is it - com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

Comment: you have to clean and build your application after changing `application.properties`

Comment: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'. / 2019-05-29 17:03:36.162  WARN 16528 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource

Comment: can you add your `springapplication.java` to your question. click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56358588/edit) to edit

Comment: also, you are missing `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` in your application.properties

Comment: @TechatTheSparksFoundation yes I did not mention it here, but later I added that line in application.properties. I am doing the build including that.

Comment: The credentials of username ,  password, port (3306) and  db (dbase) you are trying to connect are correct right?

Comment: @Filip123go yes, the credentials are correct.

Comment: Can you  access your db via a db management program (e.x. dbeaver or datagrip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change quite few things

1.Goto your mysql installed directory in C drive and find `my.ini` file.

Change default_authentication_plugin to this

```
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
```

2. and then goto your MySQL command line client,
   After logging in, run this query:

   ALTER USER 'yourusername'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'yourpassword';

then restart the mysql service and run your program.

replace `"yourusername"` and `"yourpassword"` with your actual username and password of MySQL.

3. Goto POM and replace:

   ```
       <dependency>
           <groupId>mysql</groupId>
           <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
           <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>
   ```

with latest MySQL8 connector

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.15</version>
</dependency>
```

i hope it helps :)

Comment: No it didn't work. Also my mysql connector is "mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42".

Comment: Update it to (mysql-connector-java-8.0.16) because u r using mysql8

Comment: Are you restarting the sql service or not ?

Comment: Where should I keep the file then (the MySQL connector jar file) in the MySQL bin or tomcat bin?

Comment: Yes I am restarting the service everytime

Comment: Yes Sir, the solution has worked for me. Thank you for the guidance Sir.

Answer (score 0):

These are the things to check

1. Verify if the database server up and running, and your connection details are working fine in a standalone test.
2. Grant access if not present, visit :

[Host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)

3. Why are you running spring boot within tomcat in the first place and not as a fat jar ?
   Secondly, the mysql client JAR should be included in tomcat library
4. Increase mySQL max connection count, if server is running out of available connections