# Unable to connect to Docker Mysql from windows host

Tags: mysql, windows, docker

I have taken the latest docker image of mysql but I am unable to connect to it from windows host machine.

Executed the following commands:

```
 docker run -p 3306:3306 --hostname=sql --name=mysql_working -d mysql/mysql-server:latest
```

I can see the IP address with the following command:

```
docker inspect --format "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" 3ddbeeeb27e9enter
```

When I do telnet, it is timing out

```
telnet sql 3306
```

same for ping

```
ping <ip address from docker>
```

Can anyone please advise on whats missing?

Comment: The `docker run -p` option should make the service available on your host's IP address at that port (or, if you're using Docker Toolbox, the `docker-machine ip` address).  The `docker inspect` IP address is not useful for many practical purposes and you never need to look it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are exposing the port `3306` so the Sql container is available to your host.

If you are on Windows machine type `ipconfig`

Or for Linux:

`ifconfig` or `ip addr` to find your host machine's IP Address and use that IP to connect to Sql.

You can also check docker container logs by `docker logs -f container_id` here `-f` is for following the logs.

Answer (score 0):

step1: you need to the changed the default password of MySQL after the first install in docker container

```
docker logs <container_name or container_id>
docker logs <container_name or container_id> 2>&1 | grep GENERATED
```

step2:notedown default password

step3:

```
docker exec -it <container_name or container_id> mysql -uroot -p
```

Enter default password

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

For more info of step1 to step 3 [check here](https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server)

step4:Add new user in mysql as username root and host any with password

```
create user 'root'@'%' identified by 'password';
```

step5:Grant all permission to that user

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%' with grant option;
```

For more info of step4 to step 5 [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)

step 6: Exit from docker container: press `ctrl+p+q` keys (not plus key combination of ctrl with p and q)

step7: suppose you are on hostmachine then 
(else you give ipaddress of hostmachine instead of localhost)

```
telenet -l root localhost 3306
```

It asks for password enter password (we given password as password in step4)

press `ctrl+]` key (not plus key combination of ctrl with ])

Telent connect successfully ..!!