# MySQL workbench cannot connect to MySQL-docker-image inside EC2

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, mysql-workbench

1. I created an EC2 with a free tier. Inside EC2, I install docker stuff.
2. I followed, this [tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/5.5/en/docker-mysql-getting-started.html), to install `mysql/mysql-server:8.0.19-1.1.15`.
3. I created new users, with `root` and `foo`, and of course passwords for these users.
4. I ran the docker image with exposing port 3306 and tried connecting to it from MySQL Workbench.

The information I filled in for the connection

```
Hostname: #IPv4 Public IP of my EC2

Port: 3306 

Username: foo
```

But I got the following error

[image]

Any ideas for my problem?

Comment: What exactly did you do to run the image?  There are two separate Docker verbs "expose" and "publish", which sound similar, but "expose" does almost nothing.  In an EC2 context there are also security groups to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for your question, @DavidMaze! I meant **run image** by executing `docker run --name=mysql-testing -d -p 3306:3306 mysql/mysql-server:8.0.19-1.1.15`. Could you please share with me what things regarding security I should take care of?

Answer (score 0):

I just figure out the solution. It is probably about the security problem

[image]

There are a few points you should take care

1. Connection Method: Standard TCP/IP over SSH
2. SSH Hostname is the **Public DNS (IPv4)** of your EC2 instance
3. SSH Key File is the thing you downloaded when creating EC2
4. You might get the error **Access Denied for User 'foo'@'bar' (using password: YES) - No Privileges?**. To solve this, try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1559992/5657159)