# How to connect Power BI Desktop to MYSQL Database on my local Machine?

Tags: mysql, powerbi

I tried to connect from Power BI Desktop to MySQL to get data from MySQL database into Power BI but got an error message and I do not know how to fix this. Can someone please help me out?
This is the error message I keep on getting.
The error message is:

`Details: "MySQL: Host 'DELL-PC' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"`

I have also tried editing my settings on Power BI by going to file|options & settings|data source settings but still could not fix it.

Please how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

That's a database permission error, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server), you may need to create a new user (or edit the current one) with proper permissions