# How to properly connect MySQL database with C# application?

Tags: c#, mysql, azure, ado.net

I am trying to connect my `MySQL` database with `C#` but it's not getting connected.

I am using

```
static string connstring = @"server=my.live.ip;userid=user;password=123;database=db_name;port=3306";
```

but still I am getting

> Authentication to host 'my.live.ip' for user 'user' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'user'@'202.xxx.xxx.xxx' (using password: NO)`

I have searched on it but didn't find any suitable solution(s).

**P.S:** The `live IP` that I am using is of `azure`. i.e. `MySQL` database is hosted on azure server via `xampp`

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Is the user `user` on MySQL server is allowed to be connected from host `202.xxx.xxx.xxx`?

Comment: It is allowed to be connected with any host

Comment: It working perfectly with my PHP application

Comment: Are you able to connect from any other host using the same user?

Comment: Yes I am using `SQLyog` installed at my system and from there I am accessing the db

Comment: @SirRufo I don't want to buy any more new space.

Comment: If it works from your PHP app, and from the same location, then you have a different or incorrect connection string. I don't use MySql so I don't know what connection string attributes are valid, but [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-connection-string#adonet) shows different attributes than you are using. You can also copy the connection string right from the portal.

Comment: The link given shows the connection string of that DB which is hosted on azure portal. I am using xampp install in the server

Comment: What does xampp have to do with it? If you are writing .NET code you use the connection string you can obtain in the portal.

Comment: I concur with @Crowcoder. Have you tried matching the server details with what is configured on Azure portal.

Answer (score 2):

`(using password: NO)` says that no password was provided.  I am not familiar with the connection syntax for C#, but I would suspect that something is wrong with

```
static string connstring =
     @"server=my.live.ip;userid=user;password=123;database=db_name;port=3306";
```

Or perhaps `connstring` is not being used.

Also check the MySQL side.  Do `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'202%'` or maybe `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'202.xxx.xxx.xxx'`, depending on whether you used `'202%'` or `'202.xxx.xxx.xxx'` as the "host".

You should get back something like

```
GRANT ... ON dbname.* TO 'user'@'202%' WITH AUTHENTICATION 'mysql_native_password';
```

Note: having a hostname versus an IP address may be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of possible things to try -

1. Match your server name in the connection string against what is set on Azure portal.
2. Looks like the username and password you mentioned are dummy ones (understandably so). Check if your actual user name or password have any special characters, you will have to encode them appropriately to escape.

For example, if your password is my>Pass, connection string should look like this.
`static string connstring = @"server=servername;userid=user;password=my&gt;Pass;database=db_name;port=3306";`

Here is a [full list](https://forums.asp.net/post/5463303.aspx) if you would like to explore.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
namespace AzureMySqlExample
{
class MySqlCreate
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Server = "YOUR-SERVER.mysql.database.azure.com",
            Database = "YOUR-DATABASE",
            UserID = "USER@YOUR-SERVER",
            Password = "PASSWORD",
            SslMode = MySqlSslMode.Required,
        };

        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Opening connection");
            await conn.OpenAsync();

            using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS inventory;";
                await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Finished dropping table (if existed)");

                command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE inventory (id serial PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(50), quantity INTEGER);";
                await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Finished creating table");

                command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO inventory (name, quantity) VALUES (@name1, @quantity1),
                    (@name2, @quantity2), (@name3, @quantity3);";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name1", "banana");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity1", 150);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name2", "orange");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity2", 154);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name3", "apple");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity3", 100);

                int rowCount = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Number of rows inserted={0}", rowCount));
            }

            // connection will be closed by the 'using' block
            Console.WriteLine("Closing connection");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press RETURN to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It is customary to explain why your answer solves the problem instead of just dumping code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just look it up but here’s come code anyway that I found:

Replace all port # usernames and password database name and server ip with what you need.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace Deportes_WPF
{

public partial class Login : Window
{
private MySqlConnection connection;
private string server;
private string database;
private string user;
private string password;
private string port;
private string connectionString;
private string sslM;

public Login()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    server = "server_name";
    database = "database_name";
    user = "user_id";
    password = "password";
    port = "3306";
    sslM = "none";

    connectionString = String.Format("server={0};port={1};user id={2}; password={3}; database={4}; SslMode={5}", server, port, user, password, database, sslM);

    connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
}

private void conexion()
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        MessageBox.Show("successful connection");

        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + connectionString);
    }
}

private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    conexion();
}
}

}
```

I hope this code works for you.

It also looks like for the error you gave me that the username or password is invalid.

Comment: For an MySQL azure just put you azure URL where the server name/IP address is.

Comment: Still getting same issue :(

Comment: Ok, I’ll keep looking for something.

Comment: Looks like the username or password is incorrect. Have your checked them?

Answer (score 0):

> Try this:

```
const string connStr = "Server=my.live.ip; User=user; Database=db_name; Password=123; port=3306; 
    Allow Zero Datetime=true; Convert Zero Datetime=true;";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace AzureMySqlExample
{
    class MySqlCreate
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                Server = "YOUR-SERVER.mysql.database.azure.com",
                Database = "YOUR-DATABASE",
                UserID = "USER@YOUR-SERVER",
                Password = "PASSWORD",
                SslMode = MySqlSslMode.Required,
            };

            using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Opening connection");
                await conn.OpenAsync();

                using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS inventory;";
                    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine("Finished dropping table (if existed)");

                    command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE inventory (id serial PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(50), quantity INTEGER);";
                    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine("Finished creating table");

                    command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO inventory (name, quantity) VALUES (@name1, @quantity1),
                        (@name2, @quantity2), (@name3, @quantity3);";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name1", "banana");
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity1", 150);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name2", "orange");
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity2", 154);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name3", "apple");
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity3", 100);

                    int rowCount = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Number of rows inserted={0}", rowCount));
                }

                // connection will be closed by the 'using' block
                Console.WriteLine("Closing connection");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press RETURN to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

you can refer the link below to create and access mysql db using c#
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/connect-csharp

Answer (score 0):

Does your password start with `#` or similar character and you are storing it in some config file like `ini`

As some config types treat some of the special characters as either comments or something else, password becomes `null`.

To verify, change your password to alphanumeric once and test. I faced this with my passwords when I used like `password=#strongP`