# Problem with Connecting C# Code to MySQL Database

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I'm trying to make MySQL Connector 8.0.33.1 show in the Visual Studio references (what is showing there is still version 7 even though I've uninstalled that). The version that is there does not support "caching_sha2_password" authentication, which is causing me problems. What should I do?

I tried adding it to the NuGet packages and clearing the cache of the NuGet Package Manager and I tried re-starting the Visual Studio, but all that didn't work. I had thought that by doing all these, the proper MySQL.Data version would appear in the extensions.

Comment: on azure or own server? check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62097919/how-to-properly-connect-mysql-database-with-c-sharp-application

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you talking about a problem with your application? Database drivers are added through NuGet packages, not library references. Oracle's driver is way too buggy too, so almost everyone uses the truly open source [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector) driver, which has *more* downloads than Oracle's own driver.

Comment: You can't fix product bugs or missing features by reinstalling or clearing caches anyway.

Comment: Besides MySQL.Data [never realeased any version 7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/#versions-body-tab) or at least, there's no such version in NuGet any more. Versions go directly from `6.10.9` to `8.0.11`. Please post your `.csproj` and `obj\project.assets.json` files. The `.csproj` file contains the NuGet packages you added as `PackageReference` elements. The `project.assets.json` contains all dependencies, both direct and indirect. Perhaps you're using some other package that depends on a v7 version, like Oracle's MySQL provider for Entity Framework

Comment: If cleaning the cache still doesn't work, you can use the truly open source MySqlConnector driver