# Unable to connect MYSQL database in host machine from docker container

Tags: c#, mysql, database, windows, docker

I have deployed a .net application as docker container which is trying to connect to mysql database placed in host machine.
This is the error I am getting when i am running the container

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Host 'host.docker.internal' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL
server
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at NetworkBridge.Program.MySql(String server, String database) in C:\src\Program.cs:line 91
All done. Press any key to finish...
```

I have tried many solution over google,but nothing works for me!

Comment: what is on line 91?

Comment: Line 91 has code to create MySql connection instance using connection string.

I used host.docker.internal

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server