# Host --- is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server .Net core

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core

I face the problem when connecting my web application to localhost Mysql server.
This is the problem that I found:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes spacing and Order of parameters in connection string matters.

Remember documentation states "If you do not specify a server, localhost is assumed."

```
Server=myServerAddress; Port=1234; Database=myDataBase; Uid=myUsername; Pwd=myPassword;
```

Make sure your database server is running if its not running then its not able to make connection and bydefault mysql running on 3306 so don't need mention port if same in case of port number is different then we need to mention port