# Why I am not allowed to log in phpMyAdmin in remote IP (OpenServer)?

Tags: mysql

phpMyAdmin throws an error whe I try to log in using remote IP.
[image: img]

[image: img]

If I set localhost in setting I am succeed to log in phpMyAdmin.
I didn't have this error lately. It started when I updated OpenServer.

Comment: root has usually all privileges which makes it very dangerous to allow access from everywhere, so it is usually restricted to localhost.

Comment: And how I can be able to log in ? what login and password should use ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)

Comment: Where should I write in it in OpenServer ?

Comment: you have to run the command in the link directly in mysql

Comment: Where is mysql folder located in OpenServer ?