# How to connect remotely to mysql running inside a digitalocean droplet

Tags: mysql, laravel, kubernetes, digital-ocean

I have a mysql instance running inside a digitalocean droplet. Originally, we also had a laravel application running inside that droplet with the mysql instance but now we want to move our application to kubernetes.

The application has been deployed to kubernetes and we are trying to connect the laravel application to the MySQL instance inside that droplet for the purpose of testing but we keep getting the error:

Host '46.101.81.14' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

That is not IP address I specified as the host, and it is not the IP address of my kubernetes loadbalancer either.

These are the steps I took to enable remote access to the database:

- set bind address for MySQL to 0.0.0.0
- CREATE USER ‘someuser’@'localhost’ IDENTIFIED BY 'password’;
- GRANT ALL ON databasename.* TO remoteuser@'ipaddressofk8s_lb’
  IDENTIFIED BY 'password’;
- sudo ufw allow from ipaddress_of_k8s_lb to any port 3306

Please what could I be missing?

Comment: I'm encountering a similar problem, what was your solution in the end?

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow access.
may this one help you.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-mysql

Comment: I already followed all the steps in that article.

Comment: "Host '46.101.81.14' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server" 
this shows there is an issue with access so please rechack the access process. 
this might help you. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server